# Clustered Index on fact table with many sites

Tags: database, database-design, indexing, data-warehouse, database-performance

I'm trying to work out what field(s) to use for the **clustered index of my fact tables** (which all have  a similiar structure). I'll use FactSales as an example

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FactSales
(
DateOfSaleKey int NOT NULL, -- PK,
--ProfitCentreKey int NOT NULL, -- (maybe add this?)
RevenueCentreKey int NOT NULL, -- PK
TransactionHeaderNumber int NOT NULL, -- PK
TransactionDetailNumber int NOT NULL, -- PK
TableNumber int NOT NULL,
TransactionOrCheckNumber int NOT NULL,
TerminalKey int NOT NULL,
CashierKey int NOT NULL,
TimeSlotKey int NOT NULL,
TransactionTypeKey int NOT NULL,
TransactionDetailTypeKey int NOT NULL,
MediaKey int NOT NULL,
SaleItemKey int NOT NULL,
SaleTypeKey int NOT NULL,
SalesQuantity int NOT NULL,
SalesGross smallmoney NOT NULL,
SalesNet decimal (16, 8) NOT NULL,
VAT decimal (16, 8) NOT NULL,
...
)
```

**Loading**: 
The fact tables are loaded by ProfitCentre (*ProfitCentreKey*), which is a single restaurant,  and by day (*DateOfSaleKey*). We don't have *ProfitCentreKey* in the table, because we have the more granular *RevenueCentreKey*, which is a section within a restaurant.

So, each load looks like this:

```
DELETE s
FROM FactSales s
INNER JOIN DimOrganisation o ON s.RevenueCentreKey = o.RevenueCentreKey
WHERE s.DateOfSaleKey = 20160105 AND o.ProfitCentreKey = 385

INSERT INTO FactSales (DateOfSaleKey, RevenueCentreKey, ...)
SELECT DateOfSaleKey, RevenueCentreKey, ... FROM #SalesForProfitCentreAndDateOfSale
```

What I'm considering...

**(1) Clustered Index: DateOfSaleKey.** 
This might make the INSERT easier, but I'm not sure about the DELETE.

**(2) Clustered Index: DateOfSaleKey, ProfitCentreKey.** 
I would have to add ProfitCentreKey to the table. It  might make the DELETE easier, but would it fragment the table as ProfitCentreKey would not load sequentially

And the DELETE would be simplier:

```
DELETE FROM FactSales WHERE DateOfSaleKey = 20160105 AND ProfitCentreKey = 385
```

Any advice would really help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi If only concern is delete.

you should use Partitioned table.
 Create partitioned function on ProfitCentreKey  .
 Then switch the portion.